# Save canvas drawings on bitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, surfaceview

I'm using a SurfaceView and canvas. Over time The canvas draws the same bitmap image but at different position. So every time the position of the bitmap moves, any drawings on the bitmap has to be be moved as well. So is there a way to just have the drawings on the bitmap image stay so that when the image moves(when canvas redraws the bitmap at a different location on screen), any drawings on the image moves with it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a `Bitmap` to be the backing buffer for your canvas so that drawing to the canvas is, effective, drawing to that `Bitmap`.  This way you can keep it around and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: How do I set the backing buffer to canvas?

Comment: You just pass it into the constructor.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)